# Why does Mozilla Javascript Debugger's breakpoint snap to function declaration?

Tags: javascript, breakpoints, mozilla

I have a web page with tons of JS in it and I'm trying to set a breakpoint on a line inside one function.  When I click on the line, the blue dot slides down to the next function's declaration. The closest I can get to the line I want is at the declaration of the function it's inside of.

Is this a setting? Is there something it can't parse, or which tells it the line will never be hit?  (BTW, even when set at the declaration, the break point is never hit, although the function is doing its job.)

Comment: Is this code minified at all or running through source maps?

Comment: The code in question is served as-written, but the supporting libraries are in various states of minification.

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace is ignored. The breakpoint will bind itself to whatever the next action is:

```
1    function one (y) {
2                      <=== selecting here will slide it down to line 3
3        var x = y;
4                      <=== selecting here will slide it down to line 7
5    }
6
7    function two () {
8        console.log("Hi");
9   }
```

if you want to see the state at the end of `function one()`, I typically just add a quick `console.log()` and bind my breakpoint to it:

```
1    function one (y) {
2
3        var x = y;
4        console.log() <=== bind your breakpoint to this line
5    }
```

Comment: Thanks - this is good general info, but there are no blank lines in the fn's, and I've been attempting to break on an assignment statement. In your example, if I click on line 3, the bp slides to line 7.  --Is it possible that the line-wrapped, line-numbered visualization in the debugger is an illusion and the entire fn is actually only 1 line?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide code/examples it will make it easier for us to give you an accurate answer.

If [@cdbajorin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36023984/641833)'s answer does not solve your issue try adding [`debugger;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) before the first line you want to start debugging.  This will cause the execution to stop (as long as the debugger is open).

[It is compatible with all major browsers.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_debugger.asp)

Comment: What's the best way to add a movie of the behavior? There are no blank lines in the 2 functions, yet the breakpiont slides to the fn declaration, no matter what actual statement I click on.

Comment: @user1944491 We don't need a movie, just the code and an indication of where you are trying to add the break point.  Feel free to change the variable names a long as it still runs.  Be sure to include everything in the {} which contains the location you are trying to debug.  Also, did you try adding `debugger;` as I suggested above?